# Error compiling glibc on mac

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, glibc

I'm trying to compile glibc on my mac (os x 10.6.6) as: `../glibc-2.13/configure --prefix=/dev1/cu`
but its coming up with:

```
configure: running configure fragment for add-on build.glibc
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: $CXX
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-c'
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-c is typically an option which specifies that you do not want to link the files yet. This is supported by at least all recent versions as far as I'm aware. Could you try to figure out what the value of $CXX is? That tells us more about your compiler.

Comment: and you do have g++ installed? Can you give me the output of `g++ --version`

Comment: g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Okay, So I don't have a mac, therefore I have to keep guessing a bit, but: are you sure it is `/dev1/`, rather than `/dev/`? And I suppose you are writing to a device this way? How about mounting it first to `/media/extdevice`, and then using `--prefix=/media/extdevice`?

Comment: /dev1 is a folder i made, short for developer1